# Parsing SVG file - decomposing transformation matrix

Tags: geometry

I need to parse SVG (just the simples things) and only thing left to do is to properly extract position and angle from the matrix transformation. I know this question has been asked many times and I believe I have went through many of the answers, documents etc. but still cannot handle it proporly. Here's the simplest example I managed to prepare:

I have created 1000x1000 document (all numbers in px) and put a rectangle of 100x100 size at 100,100 position. It has generated the following piece of SVG file (I have removed style attrib. and parent tags). There's no other transformation anywhere in the file:

```
    <rect
       width="100"
       height="100"
       x="100"
       y="100" />
```

Then I have rotated the rectangle by 33deg (with the 'transform' inkscape tool). The SVG code looks this:

```
   <rect
       width="100"
       height="100"
       x="-5.8952699"
       y="157.49644"
       transform="matrix(0.83867057,-0.54463904,0.54463904,0.83867057,0,0)" />
```

Now, my goal is to extract the position and angle from the matrix, so basically I'd like to get back the following values: x:100,y:100,angle:33. In order to do it, I have assumed the following formulas:

```
sx=sqrt(a^2+b^2)
sy=sqrt(c^2+d^2)

t=atan(c/d) OR t=atan(-b/a)
t=acos(a) if MATRIX is PURE

x' = tx + sx*(COS(t)*x-SIN(t)*y)
y' = ty + sy*(SIN(t)*x+COS(t)*y)
```

the result is:
t = 0.575958787 (which is 33deg) - PERFECTLY FINE

however
x'=-90.72230563 and y'=128.8770646
and this is exactly what totally confuses me - why it's not 100,100 ?

Please help, I have went through tons of forums, SVG W3C documentation and still cannot make it right.

Thank you,
Veedoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** Combine everything into a single matrix. This might be avoided, but it makes the subsequent discussion more uniform, since you won't have to worry about more than a single transformation. To get this matrix, combine the specified position (which is an implicit translation) with the given transformation matrix:

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
0.83867057 & 0.54463904 & 0 \\
-0.54463904 & 0.83867057 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -5.8952699 \\
0 & 1 & 157.49644 \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\\
=\begin{pmatrix}
0.83867057 & 0.54463904 & 80.8345205177 \\
-0.54463904 & 0.83867057 & 135.298423247 \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

**Step 2:** Identify rotation (and possiby scaling). The upper left $4\times4$ block of $M$ has the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
s\cdot\cos\varphi & -s\cdot\sin\varphi \\
s\cdot\sin\varphi & s\cdot\cos\varphi
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\varphi$ is the angle of rotation and $s$ is the global scale factor. You can therefore compute
\begin{align*}
s &= \sqrt{0.83867057^2 + 0.54463904^2} \approx 1 \\
\tan\varphi &= \frac{-0.54463904}{0.83867057} \\
\varphi &= \operatorname{atan2}(-0.54463904, 0.83867057)
= -0.575958656219877 \approx -33°
\end{align*}
So your scaling is negligible (and due to rounding errors), while your rotation is by the $33°$ you mentioned, but in the opposite direction as you might have thought, due to different conventions as to which direction is positive.

**Step 3:** Find center. The position $(100, 100)$ in the original document denoted the upper left corner of the rectangle. But as a first step, you should have a look at the center. The dimension of the rectangle is still given as $100\times100$. So take the point $(50,50)$ and apply $M$ to it.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0.83867057 & 0.54463904 & 80.8345205177 \\
-0.54463904 & 0.83867057 & 135.298423247 \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}50\\50\\1\end{pmatrix}
\approx\begin{pmatrix}150\\150\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

So you now know that the *center* of the rectangle is located at $(150,150)$. From this and the original size, you can deduce that the original top left corner must have been $(100,100)$.